# Dock won't position on the bottom

Tags: macos, dock

How do I get the Dock to go to the bottom on my Mac Pro with Yosemite?  It will go on either side, but not the bottom.  It goes on the bottom on my Macbook Pro, but not the Mac Pro.

Comment: Are you using any third party software such as “Onyx”?

Comment: Could you expand what you mean by 'not the bottom'? Do you get any errors when you try this? What is preventing you from selecting the option?

Comment: Have you tried logging out and back in? Do you have multiple displays, with another display logically below the one you're trying to put the Dock on? How are you trying to move the Dock? (Shift-drag of the divider? Dock menu→Position on Screen? System Preferences→Dock?) Maybe try another way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to restart your Dock by opening Terminal app in your Utilites folder and running the following command:

```
killall Dock
```

Comment: Repairing Permissions is an utter waste of time, especially in a situation like this where there is no indication of a permissions problem on anything installed as a system file.

Comment: @ganbustein I guess you are right on that! = deleted that part.